# NodeJS and ReactJS - Backend messages don't arrive in the frontend when the app is in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs

On localhost it works normally 100%, no error occurs.
In production it also works, but I don't get any error messages.

I was using redux and removed it because I thought it was a problem with it, but that's not the case... the problem still appears even in the form below.

**This is my backend authentication**:

```
exports.userLogin = async (req, res) => {

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });

    if (!user) {
        // Here the message that should appear
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'No users found.' });
    }
    const comparePassw = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!comparePassw) {
        // Here too
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Incorrect password.' });
    }

    const { id, username, confirmed } = user;

    return res.json({
        user: { id, username, confirmed },
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        token: generateToken(user)
    });
};
```

**Frontend request(I'm using Axios)**:

```
const postDataAPI = async (post, token) => {
  const res = await api.post(`/users/login`, post, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo?.token}` }
  })
  return res;
}
```

**And here is the page that submits**:

````
        UsersRepo.postDataAPI(data)
            .then(response => {
                localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(response.data))
               history.push("/");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                toast.error(err.response.data.error)
            })
    };
    ```
````

Comment: What does the network-tab of your browser tell you? What is the statuscode of the request from your frontend to your backend in production? Or do the request get resolved at all? Could the code in `User.findOne({ where: { email } })` possibly run forever without a timeout leading to the request stop at that line?

Comment: Through console.log I see the statuses work correctly according to the errors, the only problem is the message does not appear.

Comment: Is your error actually catched insde `UsersRepo.postDataAPIs catch`? Can you simply console.log the error in the catch in addition to sending it to toast?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using createAsyncThunk, to receive the correct message from your backend add

```
try {

// your code

}catch(err: any) {

return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data)

})}
```

after using createAsyncThunk in your component just retrieve the message: `err.message`